# What can I do if my English level is lower than the minimum requirements?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, language-exams, ielts

I am applying for a Masters degree. An  IELTS with an **overall** Band score of at least **6.5** and a minimum of **6.0** for **each section** is required. I have taken the test and my **overall** score is **7** but in particular my score is:

Listening:  8.5 
Reading:    7.5 
Writing:    7.0 
Speaking:   **5.5**

1. Would an application with the aforementioned results get rejected before it even reaches the academic evaluation stage?
2. Would an Enquiry on Results (apply for my speaking to be remarked) help?
3. Is retaking the test the best option?

Comment: I am somewhat familiar with IELTS as that is an English test required by the UK Immigration for applying to work/study/stay in the UK. The Uni programme requirement is likely there to comply with a higher requirement. And even though I remember that for study visas (as opposed to work ones), the Uni could set it's own language requirements or assessment, I would assume using a suggested route would be administratively simpler. And if the Uni policy really is set somewhere higher up the hierarchy, it is unlikely that they are able to make exceptions.

Comment: Likely your only option is to improve your English and pass the test -- requirements are often government, not university, policy. From the small sample in your question and your grades except speaking, your English looks fine to me, so you probably just need more speaking practice.

Answer (score 5):

The higher up the requirements are imposed, the less flexibility there is for circumventing the policy.

The reason for having such policies may be related to satisfying needs for teaching assistants and for being able to handle the communication needed for taking coursework.

Your best recourse is probably to retake the test, rather than trying to get an exception that could cause problems later on if a new set of policies are put into place.

Comment: Where I did the PhD, they were quite lenient when it came to the language requirements. You could take your tests even after enrolling, but you couldn't continue if by the end of the first semester your English didn't improve.

Comment: @Magicsowon Depending on how often this "can't continue" rule was invoked, this actually sounds worse than straight-up not accepting students with weak English.

Comment: @xLeitix They had a month long English program for new graduate students which helped a lot. Though my scores were fine, I didn't speak well, so it helped a lot. I never heard of anyone leaving the school because they flunked English.

Comment: The reason for such policies is also possibly immigration rules for foreign students